# ROR Observer doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, observer-pattern

OrderItem observer doenst calculate total sum when updating OrderItem :((
what's wrong?

```
class OrderItemObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    def after_save(order_item)
        order_item.order.total_sum = order_item.order.order_items.collect{|i| i.price.to_i}.sum     
    end
end
```

listed in application.rb

```
config.active_record.observers = :order_observer, :order_item_observer
```

Comment: Hi zakusha, can you put your developpment log when you save an order_item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is being calculated then discarded as you are not saving the result.

```
class OrderItemObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
    def after_save(order_item)
        order = order_item.order
        order.total_sum = order.order_items.collect{ |i| i.price.to_i }.sum
        order_item.save
    end
end
```

Value is now saved. The `order` variable is just to tidy things up a little.

Comment: thanks alot, now all works correctly. I mistakenly supposed that callbacks activate record save by themselves